# Modifying global variables in Python unittest framework

Tags: python, unit-testing, global-variables

I am working on a series of unit tests in Python, some of which depend on the value of a configuration variable. These variables are stored in a global Python config file and are used in other modules. I would like to write unit tests for different values of the configuration variables but have not yet found a way to do this.

I do not have the possibility to rewrite the signatures of the methods I'm testing.

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
from my_module import my_function_with_global_var

class TestSomething(self.unittest):

    def test_first_case(self):
         from config import MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE
         MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE = True
         self.assertEqual(my_function_with_global_var(), "First result")

    def test_second_case(self):
         from config import MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE
         MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE = False
         self.assertEqual(my_function_with_global_var(), "Second result")
```

Thanks.

Edit: Made the example code more explicite.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `unittest.mock.patch` as in [@Flimm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34631010/78845), if that's available to you.

---

#### Original Answer

Don't do this:

```
from my_module import my_function_with_global_var
```

But this:

```
import my_module
```

And then you can inject `MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE` into the imported `my_module`, without changing the system under test like so:

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase): # Fixed that for you!

    def test_first_case(self):
         my_module.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE = True
         self.assertEqual(my_module.my_function_with_global_var(), "First result")

    def test_second_case(self):
         my_module.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE = False
         self.assertEqual(my_module.my_function_with_global_var(), "Second result")
```

I did something similar in [my answer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271947/pyunit-simulating-input-to-stdin/6271995#6271995) [How can I simulate input to stdin for pyunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6271947/78845) .

Comment: @badzil: Excellent. Now that you have unit-test coverage, you can remove the (need for the) global variable ;-)

Comment: But is there any cons to have global variables in python to define constants ? I read that if yoy put them in the `__init__` of the module you import it is okay.

Comment: But how would you get the variable to automatically change back to the original value after the test, like with `unittest.mock.patch`?

Comment: This approach opens you up to a subtle bug, because the value of `my_module.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE` isn't reset when the test completes. If subsequent tests run in the same process use `MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE` without expecting it to be changed, your tests may fail or pass based on the order they're executed.

Comment: @ForeverWintr this isn't that subtle. It's a major drawback.

Comment: You're right. This is subtle but major drawback and is not the way I'd do things in 2017. I'm not sure mock.patch even shipped with Python in 2011 when I wrote this answer.

Comment: @Johnsyweb how about updating the answer? I'd change my downvote to an upvote since I ended up here in 2017 :)

Answer (score 84):

You probably want to mock those global variables instead. The advantage of this is that the globals get reset once you're done. Python ships with a mocking module that lets you do this.

[`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) be used as a decorator:

```
class TestSomething(self.unittest):

    @patch('config.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE', True)
    def test_first_case(self):
         self.assertEqual(my_function_with_global_var(), "First result")
```

You can also use it as a context manager:

```
    def test_first_case(self):
        with patch('config.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE', True):
            self.assertEqual(my_function_with_global_var(), "First result")
```

Comment: Fantastic approach: simple and effective. Thanks for sharing. Specially useful with @Michele 's edit.

Comment: In my case I didn't care about the initial value, but needed to verify the global was written to. That's possible using `with patch('config') as mock_config` and `self.assertEqual(True, mock_config.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE)`

Comment: Is it possible to follow a similar approach to patch a local variable in an instance method?

Comment: This does not seem to work when the global variable is used as a function's default parameter value, e.g. `def my_function_with_global_var(s=MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE)`.

Comment: This didn't work for me because my function under test was importing the global var in a different module. I was patching the module that defined the global, but you have to patch the module that imports the global (in my case the module with the function I was testing)

Answer (score 2):

You code imports `MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE` into the local scope and then immediately overwrites the name with a different object.  That won't change the value in the `config` module.  Try

```
import config
config.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE = False
```

instead.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention something else. The functions I'm testing are in a separate module and therefore have already imported the global variable I need to modify. Your proposed modification only modifies the global variable in the test file.

Comment: @badzil: Probably the best option is not to use `from config import MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE` in the modules you are testing, but rather `import config` and access the variables as `config.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE`.

Comment: Thanks. This works although I was looking to not modify the module I am testing. I'm guessing that as the module to test uses the import ... from ... directive, there is no way to change the value of the global variable after the import.

Comment: @badzil: If the value is immutable (like the `bool` in the example), than you can't change it.  That's somehow the nature of immutable objects. -- Another option is to `reload()` and reimport all modules after changing the value in `config`.