# Pytest mock global variable in subprocess.call()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, patch

A global variable can be easily mocked following [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268278/modifying-global-variables-in-python-unittest-framework). Great. However, this does not work when trying to mock a variable in a script that you call with `subprocess.call()` in a test with Pytest.

Here is my simplified script in a file called `so_script.py`:

```
import argparse

INCREMENTOR = 4


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input_nr', type=int, help='An int to increment')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(str(args.input_nr + INCREMENTOR))
```

Now, say I want to mock the value of `INCREMENTOR` in my tests to be `1`. If I do this:

```
from subprocess import call
from unittest import mock

def test_increments_with_1():
    with mock.patch('so_script.INCREMENTOR', 1):
        call(['python', 'so_script.py', '3'])
    with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
        assert f.read() == '4'
```

The test will fail, because the value of `INCREMENTOR` remains 4, even though I tried to patch it to 1. So what gets written to the file is 7 instead of 4.

So my question is: how do I mock the `INCREMENTOR` global variable in my `so_script.py` file so that, when calling `subprocess.call()` on it, it remains mocked?

Comment: Mock is used with language resources (objects). In this case, you are using a operation system resource. When you call a sub process from so, by definition you are not using a Python resource, but a so resource and assigning result, or sometimes stdout, to Python object. That's why you can't do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `so_script.py` script and pytest are executed in different processes, one cannot mock objects in `so_script.py` while the latter is being called as a different process in tests.

The best solution I found was to put everything from the `if __name__ == '__main__:` block in a function and test that function with Pytest, mocking whatever I needed to mock. And, to have 100% test coverage (which was my initial intent with calling the script as a subprocess), I applied [this solution](https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/how-to-test-if-name-main-1928367290cb).

So I dropped using `subprocess.call()` in my tests and wrote an `init()` function checking `if __name__ == '__main__:`, and then mocked `__name__` in the tests to test the function, just as the article advises to do. This got me 100% test coverage and full mocking capabilities.